# How to deal with delay api response in react native using redux?

Tags: api, react-native, google-cloud-functions

Im building a react-native app, which when the user try to signIn, I invoike firebase.CreateUser and then an api from firebase function to create that user in my database (Firebase Real-Time). The problem is that when the componentDidUpdate is executed, I still don't have the result from my firebaseFunction, then my props only update if I tap in screen. I would like to know how to deal with that.
Im using redux.

Follow my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image,Alert} from 'react-native';
import logo from '../../asserts/logo.png'
import { TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Divider,Input} from 'react-native-elements';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signupUser} from '../../store/actions/Section/actions';


class Signin extends Component {

state = {
    fullName:'',
    userName:'',
    email:'',
    password:'',
    confirmPassword:'',
    bornDate:'',
    State:'',
    City:''
};

      handleEmailChange = val => {
        this.setState({ email:val });
    };

    handlePasswordChange = val => {
        this.setState({ password:val });
    };

    handleConfirmPasswordChange = val => {
        this.setState({ confirmPassword:val });
    };

    handleNameChange = val => {
        this.setState({ fullName:val });
    };

    handleUserNameChange = val => {
        this.setState({ userName:val });
    };

    handleStateChange = val => {
        this.setState({ State:val });
    };

    handleCityChange = val => {
        this.setState({ City:val });
    };
    handleBornDateChange = val => {
        this.setState({ bornDate:val });
    };



    onSignInUser = () => {

        const {email,password} = this.state
        if(email=='' || password=='')
            return;

        this.props.signUp(this.state.fullName,this.state.userName, this.state.email,this.state.password,this.state.confirmPassword,this.state.bornDate,this.state.State,this.state.City);   
       // this.props.navigation.navigate('User');
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { idUser, loading,error } = this.props;
    console.log(idUser);
    console.log('aqui');
    if (!loading && error) Alert.alert('Erro', error);
    if (!loading && idUser) this.props.navigation.navigate('User');
  }

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.flexCenter}>
            <Image source={logo} style={styles.logoImage}/>
            <Text style={styles.logoText} >HomeShare</Text>
            <Text style={styles.sublogoText} >SignUp</Text>
        </View>
        <Divider style={styles.divider} />
        <View style={styles.flexButton}>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Input style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={this.handleNameChange} value={this.state.fullName} placeholder='Nome'/>
                <Input style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={this.handleUserNameChange} value={this.state.userName}  placeholder='User'/>
                <Input style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={this.handleBornDateChange} value={this.state.bornDate}  placeholder='Nascimento'/> 
                <Input style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={this.handleStateChange} value={this.state.State}  placeholder='Estado'/> 
                <Input style={styles.textInput } onChangeText={this.handleCityChange} value={this.state.City}  placeholder='Cidade'/> 
                <Input style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={this.handleEmailChange} value={this.state.email} placeholder='E-mail' keyboardType={'email-address'}/>
                <Input style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={this.handlePasswordChange} value={this.state.password}  placeholder='Senha' secureTextEntry={true}/>
                 <Input style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={this.handleConfirmPasswordChange} value={this.state.confirmPassword}  placeholder='Confirme sua Senha' secureTextEntry={true}/>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={this.onSignInUser} >
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SignIn</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{marginTop:10}}>Ou</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={this.signInUser}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Entrar com Facebook</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}


}



const mapStateToProps = ({ section: { restoring, loading, user, error, logged, idUser } }) => ({
    restoring: restoring,
    loading: loading,
    user: user,
    error: error,
    logged: logged,
    idUser: idUser
  });



  const mapDispatchToProps = {
        signUp:signupUser
  };

  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Signin);
```

My Action:

```
    export const signupUser = (fullName,userName, email,password,confirmPassword,bornDate,State,City) => dispatch => { dispatch(sessionLoading());
    firebaseService.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(user => {
    console.log(user);
                   firebaseService.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
  SectionService.signIn(idToken,fullName,userName, email,password,confirmPassword,bornDate,State,City).then((response) =>{
    console.log(response);
    dispatch(sessionSetId(response));

  }).catch(e=> {
    dispatch(sessionError(e));
  });
   }).catch(function(error) {
     dispatch(sessionError(e));
  });

 })
 .catch(error => {
  dispatch(sessionError(error.message));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

A proposed solution is to handle the account creation in the createUser callback and to update it with other data in the cloud function. Alternatively you can set up a listener that looks for the document, which will then be created and the listener will be notified.

I personally create the user doc on the client side because I create it with some data only available on the client, but your use case will be dictate your preferred approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Do you have some example of it ?

Comment: Since this method would be a proposed restructuring of your code, and you already know how to call createUser and work with cloud functions, please do feel free to make an attempt and if doesn’t work create a new question.